# Difference between Postremo and Postea?

Tags: synonyms

Is there a difference between *postremo* and *postea* which both seem to mean afterwards?

I did look in Doderlein's Handbook and he doesn't cover these two words.

Answer (score 7):

*Postremo* actually means "at last" or "finally." It is more synonymous with *tandem*. (Cf. the difference between *at last* and *finally* in English.) It's an alternate form of *postumus*. You can remember this by noticing the *-em-* superlative infix; the comparative is *posterior*.

*Postea* is the word that means 'afterwards.' You can remember that by thinking of it as *post* + *ea* ('after these things').